# Could I using memcpy to access continuously cache memory rather than __raw_writel for each and in linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, memcpy

I got 100 bytes of continuously cache memory to backup some data during warm reboot in my embedded device.

Using `__raw_writel` for each 4 of 100 would be a half screen of code. Could I using memcpy for that?

Answer (score 1):

How would it be a half screen of code? You must have a really small screen. If the memory area is continuous, you can just use a loop.

```
u32 *to_write = ...;
volatile u32 __iomem *cache = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    __raw_writel(to_write[i], cache + i);
}
```

Whether memcpy will work with your cache memory depends on the architecture and the implementation of memcpy for that architecture.

Comment: That probably works on all compilers supported by the linux kernel, but it's important to note that arithmetic on `void*` is illegal C code.  Using `char*` would be portable.

Comment: Arithmetic on `void *` is a GCC extension that is widely used in the kernel.